# Objective-C class naming convention vs Uncle Bob

Tags: objective-c, coding-style

In `Chapter 2: Meaningful Names` Uncle Bob writes:

> **Don't Add Gratuitous Context**
>
> In an imaginary application called "Gas Station Deluxe," it is bad idea to prefix every class with `GDS`. Frankly, you are working against your tools. You type `G` and the press completion key and are rewarded with a mile-long list of every class in your system

Actually that what I discovered during my first days with Objective-C a bit more than one year ago. After Java it was quite disappointing but I thought I'm only one who annoyed about that :)
I understand, that "Clean Code" book refers to Java most of the time and Java has namespaces (packages) unlike Objective-C.

Do you use 2-3 letters prefix in your classes if you're building an app, not a library? 
What do you think, is it bad language design, language "feature" or Uncle Bob wasn't right here?

Comment: You may be interested to read [Mike Ash's essay about namespaced constants and functions in ObjC](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-08-19-namespaced-constants-and-functions.html).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perhaps the key word here is *gratuitous*. In Objective-C, prefixes serve the important purpose of reducing the chance of name collisions. In other languages like Java and C++, the existence of support for namespaces makes the use of prefixes gratuitous (and a violation of the oft-cited DRY principle). In Objective-C, however, prefixes are meaningful, useful, and *not* gratuitous.

Comment: Thanks. I understand WHY class prefixes are included in the language coding conventions. However I think that namespaces is much better solution and it is a bit strange that quite modern language doesn't have them.

Comment: @OgreSwamp Two things to remember about Objective-C are that it's as old as C++ (both appeared in 1983) and that in many cases it eschews features and complexity and replaces them with convention and style. Perhaps namespaces are so useful and would be such an improvement to the language that it's worth the cost of introducing them as a language feature. (I don't think so.) Anyway, my aim wasn't to explain prefixes but rather to point out that the guideline doesn't mean that prefixes are bad, only that prefixes are bad if they don't serve a purpose.

Answer (score 3):

I was tempted to close this question, but I don't think I've seen a similar one asked before and it's a valid question. Here are my rather disorganized thoughts on the matter.

Many languages have a feature called *namespaces*, where the "fully qualified" class name is prefixed by a hierarchical series of names. For example, the `String` class in Java is, properly, `java.lang.String`, and a custom class is properly `com.whatever.foobar.MyClass`.

Unfortunately, namespaces have never been added to Objective-C, which means that Objective-C symbols (class names, protocol names, and a few various other types) cannot be placed in a namespace even when using Objective-C++ (which has a namespace feature for functions, constants, structures, etc.)

The only solution to prevent symbol collisions in shared code, then, is to use some form of name mangling to make your symbol names unique. In Objective-C, the convention is to use a prefix of two characters (sometimes the number varies) for all your classes.

This Uncle Bob fellow is a twit for telling you not to do this, because while you'll end up with a program that doesn't compile, you'll lose any benefit of namespaces that prefixes still offer. Does your app use plugins? You need to prefix. Does your app have a public API? You need to prefix.

In theory, code within a single application that never touches the outside world can do without prefixes, but screw it--keep coding cleanly, and add a prefix even there. It'll save you grief later.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I almost never use prefixes. The only exceptions are classes that are somehow connected to each other or they all should be present.

An example:

Some client app for chat. Let's call that chat an `ExampleChat`.

Then I'd use `ECMessage`, `ECUser`, `ECRoom`, etc. to easily see which classes should there be.

Or if I make some custom cells for `UITableView` I'd use prefixes to keep them all close to each other and not struggle with searching them in a "mile-long list". Example:

`ECTextMessageCell`, `ECSoundMessageCell`, `ECUploadMessageCell`, `ECJoinOrLeaveMessageCell`, etc.

That's my personal opinion, which can not be the best. But it's still easiest for me.

Hope it helps

Comment: I'd put all those classes in an `ExampleChat` namespace or sub-namespace where the language allows. Prefixes are only useful when namespaces are not an option (which is what we're discussing.)

Comment: I'm with you in case of languages like objective-c where no packages/namespaces or some similar concept available for structuring the source.

Comment: That is exact situation described in Clean Code and it is mentioned as bad practice. I'm quite agree with Uncle Bob but I think that is fault of language syntax (no namespaces for classes)

Comment: It is a fault of the language, but Uncle Bob is wrong for telling readers not to use the standard workaround (prefixes.)

Comment: I wouldn't say that he is wrong. He doesn't tell not to use them. He said that it is bad naming convention. And here I would agree with him. But in Objective-C we have it as a standard naming convention which we're forced to use.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you do not have Namespaces, name conflicts are likely to occur. You can see that in a lot of C libraries  that they are using some kind of prefix. So I guess there are good reasons to have those prefixes and other reasons not to use it. But what should be the big problem to modify the completion to either just ignore the prefix of typing three letters instead of just one.

So in the end it seems to me a matter of taste. I guess it would be more important to have good structures classes with prefixes instead of a mess of classes without prefix....

It has nothing to do with bad language design IMHO. There was a time where software was not everywhere and why should one waste extra effort on namespaces? And  still as we can  see even nowadays languages without namespaces are used.....

Comment: Objecive-C 3.0 is about 1 year old or so. They had a chance to fix issue with namespaces, so argument about old times doesn't work here IMHO

Comment: Not familiar with "Objective-C 3.0." Can you provide a link to it?

Comment: I'm sorry, that was typo, 2.0. And I made a mistake that an age. It is about 5 years ago. Anyway, it isn't too old, right? :)

Answer (score 0):

I would say, that the world is not black or white. I do programming in java, with packages and yes, it is annoying to have a prefix in each class, as well as it is annoying and arguable to start interfaces with I (just like .Net used to do it).

Sometimes it does annoying me in objective-c however it has some legitimacy if you do not have packages in your language, since you can 'build' artificial groups of classes like 'NS', 'UI', 'MK' and so on in objc and cocoa.

Comment: But that is an language fault. Moreover, chances that I'll have name collision with EXMessage then in com.example.Message are million times higher.

Comment: I'm not sure if we can just label it as a fault, but rather a feature or a restriction.

Is the lack of objects and namespaces a language fault in C? I'd rather say it is part of the language's characteristic.

And if we consider language's a kind of instruments, than each of them has its own way to use. Some practices are valid or even preferable in one but absolutely no-go in another.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond avoiding collisions, one of the benefits that name prefixes gives is that you're immediately aware of what type you're really dealing with. Suppose you had the following code:

```
Color c = ...;
MultiValueMap m = ...;
```

From a cursory glance at the code and depending on what libraries you've used, those types could be from a number of different sources. You may have to lookup which include/import statement was made to understand what the type can do (e.g. you want to modify it but it's missing a method that you're sure is there).

In the iOS world, you would immediately know whether it's a UIColor vs. a CGColor and gain immediate context.

In the past at WWDC, Apple would host a session where they explained Cocoa/Objective-C coding conventions. I believe they mention this aspect of name prefixes so you might want to find one of the recordings that are made available. Other C developers (e.g. Linux kernel developers) also do not seem to think highly of C++ namespaces (among other C++ features) for various reasons.

Comment: Thanks Bryant. But I think having UIColor and CGColor in standard framework is another example of the "bad" design.